# Kafka producer slowdown

Tags: performance, asynchronous, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, slowdown

I'm trying to send messages asynchronously using idempotent Producer (1 topic, 1 partition). First 10 batches (all same size) are being sent pretty quickly (~0.1sec) but further batches take a lot more time (~10sec).

I've tried tuning linger.ms, batch.size and buffer.size but it only makes the situation better for a few more batches and after that, situation repeats.

What can be a possible reason for that and what is the possible solution?

Comment: What did you use for linger.ms? How are you calculating the send time?

Comment: Values for linger.ms were 5, 10, 20, 100, 1000 ms. I calculate the time which takes to perform serialization of my objects and also performing .send() method for each of those.

Comment: My thoughts are that .send() method is blocked due to producer's cache is being filled. I don't know if the only way to check that is to increase the size of the buffer(which is 32MB by default) or to try sending less messages.

Comment: The only settings that I know to affect the request latency are the linger.ms and the batch.size. If you do not want the producer to wait to send the record to kafka then I would set linger.ms to 0, otherwise it will wait until the batch is full. Increasing the buffer size probably won't help. You can also monitor the producer to check his average batch size and average request latency through the "getMetrics" api. The metrics are documented here [link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#producer-metrics).

Comment: You could also explicitly call flush after certain amount of time/messages

Comment: Can there be any issues on broker side like heap is full or smth else?

Comment: Maybe you can try using `kafka-producer-perf-test` to rule out broker-side issues and/or tune-up producer configs.

Comment: Can I run these tests using Java API without installing Kafka itself?

P.S. I think this one can help 
[link](https://github.com/jhooda/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/tools/ProducerPerformance.java)

Comment: This is part of standard kafka tools distro (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.0/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh), so I'm not sure what you mean "without installing Kafka".

Comment: By saying "without installing Kafka" do you mean a broker is not running? If the broker is unreachable, the send method will block until the request times out fetching the metadata. The **kafka-producer-perf-test** requires a broker to be running.

Comment: Not at all. The broker is running. I was asking if I can run those performance tests using Java API from maven repo.

Comment: @АнтонАнкушев the kafka-producer-perf-test script comes with kafka, so yes you need to install kafka in order to run it.